# Google Cloud Storage streaming upload from Python generator

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-python

I have a Python generator that will `yield` a large and unknown amount of byte data. I'd like to stream the output to GCS, without buffering to a file on disk first.

While I'm sure this is possible (e.g., I can create a subprocess of `gsutil cp - <...>` and just write my bytes into its stdin), I'm not sure what's a recommended/supported way and the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-upload-object-python) gives the example of uploading a local file.

How should I do this right?

Comment: The magic is to convert your generator into a stream that yields each time a read is performed. The Python example in your reference link demonstrates how to read the stream. This article will help you create a stream backed by a generator: https://coderscat.com/python-generator-and-yield/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [BlobWriter](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobWriter) class makes this a bit easier:

```py
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('my_object')
writer = BlobWriter(blob)

for d in your_generator:
  writer.write(d)

writer.close()
```